# Can we Externalize parameters using Excel?

Tags: apache-spark

I have lot of parameters to be externalized for that can we use `Excel` if yes, how to call an `excel file` in spark submit else what is the Ideal way to do it.

spark-submit

`spark-submit --class "com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT" --master yarn --jars /root/config-1.3.1.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar --files /root/testex.xls --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 5 /root/sparkdvtparametres_2.11-1.0.jar /root/files/output/extra_in_src /root/files/output/extra_in_dest /root/files/output/misMatch /root/files/output/DestHeader /root/files/output/SrcHeader /root/files/output/Summary /root/files/output/Summary_TimeTaken /root/files/output/TC01_ColumnStats /root/files/output/TC01_MisMatchHeaders dev`

Error:`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: --files (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)`

I have externalized connection parameters in excel testex.xls `--files /root/testex.xls` how to call the excel in spark-submit. I have hard coded the path while doing it in local it is working fine how to call the excel file in `spark-submit`

Comment: yes you can use excel and parse it using Apache POI in the driver code...

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, is there is any example or how to call the excel in `spark-submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine after I added `Apache POI jars in the class path`